# Why does my Cylon Linux Live/Install disc say that it's Lubuntu at install?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I have a "Cylon Linux" live/install DVD that I have used to install Cylon on my desktop. Works fine, install was trouble free. Now I am using the SAME install DVD to install this distro on my laptop and now the splash screen says "Cylon Linux" but it tries to install Lubuntu! It has a Lubuntu install GUI and takes you all the way to the point of saying "Lubuntu will now be installed". How did this same disk install Cylon Linux in one machine and now wants to install Lubuntu on another?

Comment: they probably just missed a bit of marketing in cloning lubuntu... say some of the fallback graphics/words for installing, I would proceed with the install since you are certain it is the same disk.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the technical details page for that distro I'd assume it derives from Lubuntu. Lubuntu derives from Ubuntu, which derives from Debian.

- http://cylonlinux.weebly.com/technical-details.html

*excerpt*

```
Package Management     : Debian Packager with APT
Desktop Environment    : Gnome Classic (also contains Unity & Gnome Shell)
Kernel Version         : 3.2.0.30.32
OS Family              : Unix-like
Source Model           : Partially Open Source (Contains non-free applications)
Current Version        : 12.04.1
Parent Distribution    : Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS
License                : Mainly the GNU GPL and various other free software
Architecture           : Intel x86 (32bit)
Installation Medium    : 2.5 GB ISO image
MD-5 Checksum          : ba092dad03317677887565a4aa0a59f1
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of all of this, but it really doesn't help me with an answer as to how I can install the intended distro on this machine. (and not Lubuntu)

Comment: @KenGingerich - if you downloaded the distro from the Cylon website then I'd expect that's what you have installed. It's not unusual for the lower level distro to still be identifiable when distros build off of them. Even Ubuntu suffers from this having this file within the `/etc` dir: `/etc/debian_version`. So I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. Thank You for the comments.